# Using Kinect V2 SDK to track ONLY head position

Tags: kinect

Another way of describing what I need is to only track a single x,y,z coordinate (preferably head) of a person. In the SDK is it possible to 'turn off' parts of skeletal tracking to improve tracking performance or is skeletal tracking either ALL on or off?

Comment: If your question is "how do I get high-quality head tracking at a distance with Kinect" then ask that in one question. Please do not post multiple questions effectively asking "Can I solve this problem with strategy A?" "Can I solve this problem with strategy B?" — this diffuses the information between multiple pages making it harder to concentrate insights and evaluate the best solutions in one place. [See also the X/Y problem](http://xyproblem.info) for how focusing on the common problem, rather than your guessed/hoped solutions, can help get more useful answers, faster.